# How to split a text(list) into sections(list) by a starting pattern in tcl

Tags: regex, list, split, tcl

For example, my text is :

```
Block 1:
   xxxxxx xxxx
   xxxxxx xxxx
   xxxxxx xxxx
Block 2:
   xxxxxx xxxx
   xxxxxx xxxx
   xxxxxx xxxx
Block 3:
   xxxxxx xxxx
   xxxxxx xxxx
   xxxxxx xxxx
```

I want to split the by the different blocks, in tcl. E.g:

```
{Block 1:
   xxxxxx xxxx
   xxxxxx xxxx
   xxxxxx xxxx}
{Block 2:
   xxxxxx xxxx
   xxxxxx xxxx
   xxxxxx xxxx}
{Block 3:
   xxxxxx xxxx
   xxxxxx xxxx
   xxxxxx xxxx}
```

Any way to make this work?
Thanks!

Comment: Any attempts so far? And what's exactly your desired output?

Answer (score 2):

Try the tcllib `textutil::splitx`` command.
(see http://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/textutil/textutil.html#8)

It can split text based on a regular expression.